# How to instruct the compiler to generate an alias for a virtual function?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, virtual, abi

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9352094/1183360) for the background.

Basically, I have the following definition of a class

```
class  MyClass {
    virtual int foo4(double, int);
};
```

Is there a way to instruct the compiler to generate two symbols that would resolve to `foo4`? That is, I want that if an executable asks for the dynamic linker to resolve `_ZN7MyClass4foo4Edi` (symbol for `MyClass::foo4(double, int)`) and some other symbol (let's say `_ZN7MyClass9reserved1Ev`, a symbol for `MyClass::reserved1()`), the dynamic linker would resolve both to `&MyClass::foo4(double, int)`. I`m using fairly modern GCC on Linux.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness (it's in a comment since you asked about GCC and linux), in VC++ you can do it using pragmas: http://nikoniko-programming.blogspot.com/2010/09/aliasing-symbol-names-during-link-time.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ it looks like this:

```
class  MyClass {
    int foo5(double, int) __attribute__((alias("_ZN7MyClass4foo4Edi")));
    virtual int foo4(double, int);
};

int MyClass::foo4(double d, int i)
{
}
```

Comment: Note that both answers have assumptions about name mangling, which can change occasionally when GCC changes version.

Answer (score 3):

In gcc, use the ["alias" attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

```
int reserved1() __attribute__((alias ("_ZN7MyClass4foo4Edi")));
```

... but I believe this will only work in the same object file as (a) definition of the symbol, so I'm not sure it will suit your uses cases: see [here](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=121). Specifically, it will only be an alias for one version of the virtual call, and won't be inherited by subclasses; additionally, you cannot use it to alias a weak symbol.